# Is it possible to return an object with more than 2 fields to an action in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-actions

I am a newbie on react redux , can I create a Action with more than 2 field?
normali an action return a object with

```
{type : same_vale, paylod : same_vale}
```

Is it possible to return from a action something like this:

```
{type : same_vale , paylod : same_vale, idx : same_vale}
```

Is this an error? it allowed only make something like that?:

```
{type : same_vale , paylod : { field1 : same_vale, idx : same_vale}
```

Thanks

Comment: The redux action should look like `{ type : <type>, payload: <payload>, meta: <meta> }` and in the `meta` you could put whatever doesn't make sense as part of the payload

Comment: it's absolutely fine to add as many fields as you want, since action is a plain javascript object. For uniformity, it's advised to add "type" and "payload" as shown in 3rd option

Comment: For what you're asking, actually you can test it out easily and do a simple console log to see what are the object being passed over at reducer

Answer (score 3):

You can do whatever you want with your actions, except it should have `action.type` property.

What is better in your question depends on case. I usually put all values in `payload` property: `payload : { field1 : some_value, idx : some_id}`